# Shared Folder is missing in the Office My Addin ribbon suddenly in Angular Office Addin Project

Tags: angular, ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins

I am currently working with an office word addin using Angular, and I had already sideload my office addin as documented [in this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins). And I was able to add them from the Insert Menu -> My Add-ins ribbon, by opening the Shared Folder menu. My issue is that, all of a sudden the Shared Folder menu is not visible anymore.

[image]

Please be noted that I had already tried the refresh button on the right corner. I have also tried sideload the add in again, by creating a new shared folder. But nothing helped. Have you ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scratching my head for a few minutes, I was able to fix this. The issue was related to a recent change in the `manifest.xml` file. In the `manifest.xml` file, under the `Resources` section, we have `<bt:Urls>`, that is where we provide the `Urls`. Below is the Url which was causing the issue.

```
<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000">
```

Please be noted that there is no closing `/`  at the end of this `Url`. Once I add that to the `Url`, everything started working fine.

```
<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000" />
```

[image]

I believe that, this is something that should be fixed, it should work as it is, even though there is no closing. What do you think?

Comment: Depends. I don't know bt:Url but it seems like it is accepting a content, so this would be valid:

`<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000">
http://myurl.com
</bt:Url>`

If this would be a valid HTML, it is no HTML Void element like "input" or something, so it definitly needs an closing tag.

Comment: if you're using office-js with npm use `npm validate` to validate the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I want to make a separate answer cause I think other people should be aware, considering the 3 hours I lost with this.

The taskpane button was missing from the ribbon because the `manifest.xml` was not a valid XML manifest.

Therefore, before committing/publishing the manifest, always validate it. If you're using npm, run

```
npm validate
```

which is a shorthand for

```
office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml
```